# How to solve the error at Arraylist

Tags: c#

```
if (!(errorlist.Contains(-1)) || !(errorlist.Contains(1))) break;
```

I couldn't understand why this code is breaking out of loop even the errorlist contains 1 in the list. When I debug, the `errorlist[0] = 1` and other indices are 0.

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 3):

you need to put `&&` instead of `||`. (if you need both of them be absent from the list at the same time)

In your case first condition suceeds.

Your list does not contain `-1`, so condition  `if(!errorlist.Contains(-1))` breaks.

EDIT

If you still need keep `||`, you can do something like

`if(!errorList.Any((p)=> { return (p == 1 ||  p== -1);}))`

if you can not use `Any`, you still can define it like

`if(!(errorList.Cotains(1) ||  errorList.Contains(-1)))`

Comment: That's not the logic I need. I need OR only but seems its making me confuse on not executing

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right

> why this code is breaking out of loop even the errorlist contains 1 in
>   the list

you want to break if and only if `errorlist` doesn't contain either `1` or `-1`:

```
  if (!((errorlist.Contains(-1)) || (errorlist.Contains(1)))) break;
```

Comment: yeah worked... even I tried this logic before but my other logic running out of loop now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is checking if the list contains *both* -1 AND 1.  I suspect you want

```
if (!(errorlist.Contains(-1)) && !(errorlist.Contains(1))) break;
```

or

```
if (!(errorlist.Contains(-1) || errorlist.Contains(1))) break;
```

Comment: Both the code didn't work. Still my list has 1. I need to process the next statement if my list contains 1, not to break.

Comment: Please edit your question to give your _exact_ requirements on when it should break.

Answer (score 0):

The `||` denotes an OR.
Therefore this reads like:

if (errorList does not contain -1) OR (errorList does not contain 1) then break.

As you can see the errorList therefore must contain -1 AND 1 to not break.

If you don't want to break if either one is present change the `||` (OR) to `&&` (AND):

```
if (!(errorlist.Contains(-1)) && !(errorlist.Contains(1))) break;
```

To achieve this alternatively you can do the following:

```
if (!(errorlist.Contains(-1) || errorlist.Contains(1))) break;
```

Which reads now:

Break if NOT (errorList contains -1 OR errorList contains 1). Note the change that the not moved in front of the whole expression and you OR the parts together before you apply the NOT.

That seems what you are trying to model.

Comment: But initially according to my requirement, the list contains 1 -1 0 0. I would pass this list to function to make non zero as zero list with my other logic. -1 got overwritten and 1 needs to overwrite to 0 only if the code is not breaking..

Comment: So the problem you have is completely different from what you are asking. The (to date) 3 answers presented answer your question accurately. I would suggest asking a different question that actually represents your problem. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question. This seems to be a case of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Am sorry @Frank J. All of your logic worked which I tried already. The question which I asked was the need. The loop breaks even though it contains 1. Let me try with other possibilities.